# Why am I getting an argument error in my Excel worksheet using this VBA procedure?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written such a VBA function in my Excel worsheet:

```
Public Function total(rng As Range, ByVal sgn As String) As Date

Dim hrs As Date

hrs = 0

For Each cell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)

If cell = sgn Then hrs = hrs + cell.Offset(1).Value

Next cell

total = hrs

End Function
```

It works fine in my worksheet when total is LE 2.3333333 (56 hours), then I am geting #ARG! error. What's wrong with this procedure?

Comment: [Sgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sgn-function) is a `VBA` function. Try e.g. `s` instead. Also declare `cell` (`Dim cell As Range`). `hrs = 0` is redundant. Use `... In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2).Cells` and `If cell.Value = ...`. An accurate description of what the code is supposed to do and some sample data and/or an image showing the desired result may help you getting a descent answer.

Comment: BTW.. you know you do not need VBA for this? You can use an excel formula to get what you want?

Comment: Thx for your help. ... In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2).Cells and If cell.Value = ... works perfectly. 
I'm counting sick leaves, courses, etc. in my worksheet. In the first row there are codes of absence, for example "s", in the second row there are hours. At the end of the second row I'm calling my function.